# Ember.js JSON API confusion

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js

I am currently trying to create a simple Ember Application with Ember version 2.2.0 and Ember Data 2.2.1. I created my REST API to follow JSON API spec v1.0, this is an example of a resource array retrieved with GET /articles

```
{
  "links" : {
    "self" : "http://localhost:8080/test-app/rest/articles"
  },
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : "5666157634499515eb7e13f0",
      "type" : "articles",
      "attributes" : {
        "title" : "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "id" : "5666157634499515eb7e13f1",
      "type" : "articles",
      "attributes" : {
        "title" : "test2"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and my articles route looks like this:

```
// routes/articles.js
...
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('article');
  }
});
```

and the model:

```
// models/article.js
...
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  text: DS.attr(),
  url: DS.attr(),
  date: DS.attr()
});
```

I followed the tutorial (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/tutorial/ember-data/) exactly. Yet when I open the view, I get a warning:

```
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using test-app@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))
```

and no data is rendered. I can see the data being requested and returned correctly, but it is interpreted in the wrong way somehow.

My question is: what is wrong? I tried to stick to the default API to not write any adapters or serializers, but it is not working.

--

UPDATE: I added the "links" section to the response object and now I get two warnings:

```
WARNING: Encountered "links" in payload, but no model was found for model name "link" (resolved model name using test-app@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("links"))
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using test-app@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))
```

--

UPDATE 2: So I got this to work by restructuring my API response to look like:

```
{
  "articles" : [ {
    "id" : "5666157634499515eb7e13f0",
    "attributes" : {
      "title" : "test"
    }
  }, {
    "id" : "5666141034499511aea5f43c",
    "attributes" : {
      "title" : "test"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

- renamed "data" to "articles" which is specific to the requested resource and to the request type (get one, get many)
- removed "attributes" from the resource objects, all attributes are now directly included
- removed all keys beside "articles" in the root object

I saw this here: [ember data no model was found for attribute name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127705/ember-data-no-model-was-found-for-attribute-name) 
I do not understand why this is working but the example at the ember tutorial is not. The tutorial is for ember 2.2.0 which is what I am using. I created my project through ember cli and then replaced the ember version 1.13 with 2.2.0.

--

Update 3: Fixed this. See my answer (I cannot accept it yet). Basically, I used the wrong REST adapter. ember-cli generates a default adapter using the RESTAdapter and this has to be changed to JSONAPIAdapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Ember uses the RESTAdapter per default. To use this response format with JSON API the JSONAPIAdapter has to be used. So in app/adapters/application.js:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    ...
});
```

and change the Content Type of each API response to `application/vpn.api+json` as described in the Spec.